# How to pass the username and password to the html begin form?

Tags: c#, html

So here im trying to pass the username and password to the POST.

```
<form class="login">
<input type="text" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password">
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginButton", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { Username,Password, }))
{ 
  <button>Login</button>
    }
</form>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me specifically what you're trying to do.  Do you mean that you already have username/password values server-side and want to include them as route values in the form action?  Why?  Or does this have something to do with the `<input>` elements which are outside of the form you're trying to build?  Why are they outside of that form?  Why are you nesting a form inside of another form?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The button should be type submit and all input elements should be inside form.
It should look like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginButton", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
        }
```